# Converting only whole number doubles in a string to an int

Tags: java, string

How would I only convert whole number doubles in a string to an int? E.g.

```
String s = "3.0^3x+x-2.1+9.0
```

Converted to:

```
s = "3^3x+x-2.1+9"
```

Comment: Use a regular expression. If you don't know regex yet, now is a great time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to separate your input string into symbols.
That would result in something like `["3.0", "^", "3", "x", "+", "x", "-", "2.1", "+", "9.0"]`

Then you make a for loop and check every symbol which is a decimal (`contains('.')`), then check if it is a whole number and replace it with a string representing the same number as an integer.

After that, you concatenate every string in the array and print it.

**EDIT:**

To split the string into symbols you can use a simple trick:

```
def isNumber(c):
    return c in "0123456789."

previous = s[0]
for(i in range(1, len(s))):
    if isNumber(previous) == isNumber(s[i]):
        insertCutAt(i)
    previous = s[i]
```

Comment: That is overkill.

Comment: @Andreas not if he is trying to make code to parse his term and calculate the answer. Then parsing it is definately a good choice, but we dont know his exact intentions.

Comment: His *exact* stated intention: Convert `3.0^3x+x-2.1+9.0` to `3^3x+x-2.1+9`. For that, your answer is overkill.

Comment: Yes yes that was his intention. Actually i meant we don't know anything beyond the mentioned intention. Might be kinda overkill, yes.